# Create HIT using wav files

Tags: amazon-web-services, wav, mechanicalturk

I am a new Requestor, and trying to create a new HIT based on the Audio Naturalness HTML template in https://requester.mturk.com/create/projects/new.

I would like to use wav files, and in the html file provided, I have modified the `audio_url` line to look like:

```
<!-- Your audio file URLs will be substituted for the "audio_url" variable when you publish a batch with a CSV input file containing multiple 
 audio file URLs -->
<source src="${audio_url}" type="audio/wav" />
```

When I'm going to publish the batch, it asks for a csv, which looks like:

```
audio_url 
https://github.com/user/voiceTTS/blob/master/Sample1a.wav
https://github.com/user/voiceTTS/blob/master/Sample1b.wav
```

However, when I go to preview the HIT, the audio files are blank, i.e. nothing plays.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This was actually an issue with hosting audio files on GitHub. I hosted them on my personal website, and it works as expected!